# Why is $y{(\log_a(x))} = \log_a{(x^y)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, logarithms

> Why is $y{(\log_a(x))} = \log_a{(x^y)}$?

I feel like I'm missing something here. Sorry if I put the title wrong..

Comment: Because $a^{y \log_a x} = \left(a^{\log_a x}\right)^y = x^y$ and (by definition) $a^{\log_a x^y} = x^y$. Since $a^x$ is a single valued function we must therefore have $\log_a x^y = y \log_a x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of the [logarithmic identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities): $$\log(a^b) = b\log(a)$$

Comment: I wonder why is my book missing this... Anyways, thank you! Case closed.

Comment: This is true if and only if $a>0$

Comment: and a is not equal to 1 ?

Comment: If $a = 1$, then $a^b = 1$ and you have $0 = b\cdot 0$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

So, check it out, when $y$ is a positive integer, $x$ is real, let's give a definition of 
$$
x^y
$$
It is of course, defined precisely the way that you think,
$$
x^y = \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x}_{y \;\text{times}}
$$
So, in particular, for $z,y$ postive integers:
$$
(x^{z})^y = \underbrace{(\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x}_{z \;\text{times}})\cdot( \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x}_{z \;\text{times}})\cdot \ldots \cdot (\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x}_{z \;\text{times}})}_{y\; \text{times}} = \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x}_{z\cdot y \; \text{times}}
$$
Now, remember that $\log_b(x)$ is the inverse function of $b^x$. So, in particular, 
$$
b^{ac}=x \longleftrightarrow \log_b(x)=ac
$$
Applying the above thoughts:
$$
\log_b(x)=\log_b(b^{ac})=\log_b\left(\underbrace{(\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a \;\text{times}})\cdot( \underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a \;\text{times}})\cdot \ldots \cdot (\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a \;\text{times}})}_{c\; \text{times}}\right)
$$
Now by properties of $\log$, (which we'll get to in a moment),
$$
\log_b\left(\underbrace{(\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a \;\text{times}})\cdot( \underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a \;\text{times}})\cdot \ldots \cdot (\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a \;\text{times}})}_{c\; \text{times}}\right)=\sum_{1}^{c}\log_b(\underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot b\cdot \ldots\cdot b}_{a\; \text{times}})$$
$$
=ac
$$
To see why $\log_b(b^x\cdot b^y) = \log_b(b^x)+\log_b(b^y)$. It is sufficient to convince yourself of the property $b^x\cdot b^y = b^{x+y}$, in a similar fashion as above. The above property allows us to break up products in the arguments of $\log$ into the sums of the $\log$'s of the components of the products